# Git Eclipse and versioning

Tags: eclipse, git, versioning

i have a project in Java developed in Eclipse Mars with my colleagues. it is based on Git and we want to put it under versioning.
Any PC can export the .jar file but we need a version of the exported file.
ex: we are at the version 1.0 of the app (app_v1.0.jar)
Person 1 does some modification to the source, commits and pushes it to the repository. Now he want to export the new .jar file with the new name app_v1.1.jar 
Person 2 pulls the new source from repository, modifies some part and exports it in app_v1.2.jar.
What we need is an automatic way to have vx.y in the name of the app and the relativity version.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How are you currently tracking the version number? Are you using git tags?

Comment: Nope. In this moment we are simply commit and push our works.

Comment: We add a comment to explain what we done. But its not a tag.

Comment: So how could this automatic system know what version number it is supposed to put to the filename?

Comment: I'm asking it. what i need to do? What are the settings to aplly to do what i want? is it possible?

Comment: What I mean is that version number is a human decision, an automatic system cannot tell if you want to increment from 1.2 to 1.3 or 2.0.